# Bootstrap-Select not showing div options

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-select

I'm using bootstrap-select plugin to show options and it's not showing the options div.

I made a script in JS to show the div options, but i have 6 selects that are using the plugin, the first one worked great, but then it stops working for the others, that means that's no solution, so I'm looking for another solution or correction.

I'm using symfony 2.

```
$('.groupSelect').selectpicker({
  container: 'body',
  dropupAuto: false
});

<div id="combo-div" class="form-group">
   <select id="sel_name" data-show-subtext="false" class="form-control groupSelect" name="name">
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the corresponding HTML and if possible create a snippet real quick?

Comment: I don't mind at all, but, the problem is in my environment. I made a demo somewhere else to test that thing out and it worked, so, I don't know where the problem could be, that's why I came here...

Comment: There. I updated the question, that's the html i'm using.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. True. It does work absolutely fine EVEN for multiple selects. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/9ed0akjL/) if that helps. Make sure you've included the CSS files as well. And if you see any console errors, it'd be easier to debug then.